# Why does iTunes require entering a password for downloads of free apps?

Tags: itunes

I'd like my daughter to have the ability to download free stuff but not apps that have a cost.

Is there a way around giving her the password  and thereby having free access to my credit card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I you don't have to enter a CC number on your iTunes account. And yes, you can change the account associated with iTunes on the device.

If you want, you could always get a small Visa gift card and enter that on the account. Once the card is out of money/expires, you can continue to download free apps but it won't let you charge anything to it.

Perhaps you can check with your bank or card issuer to see if they can block purchases from iTunes. Only do this after the iTunes account has been created and the card linked to the account.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't disable the password for free apps.

The best thing to do would be to change the password to something unique; something that you don't use for anything else, and share it with her. Explain to her that it is for only downloading free apps, and that you can see the bill from iTunes and be able to tell if she has downloaded anything that isn't free.

She won't have free access to your credit card either. She needs the expiration date and the number on the back of it, which websites, and iTunes, never save digitally.

Comment: I don't remember having to enter credit card information when I buy an app.

Comment: right. but he was concerned about her having access to it online if it were saved. but it's not saved. although you do have to enter it in at least once to purchase things